# How to evaluate custom conditions in java

Tags: java, spring, conditional-statements, eval

I want to make a condition evaluator in Java which should work as follows:

```
class ConditionEvaluator{
    String condition;
    ConditionEvaluator(String condition){
        this.condition = condition;
    }
    boolean isTrue(){
        /*
        * Code here
        */
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ConditionEvaluator c1 = new ConditionEvaluator("1==1");
    ConditionEvaluator c2 = new ConditionEvaluator("  \"hi\".equals(\"hi\")    ");
    ConditionEvaluator c3 = new ConditionEvaluator("3==4");
    System.out.print(c1.isTrue(),c2.isTrue(),c3.isTrue());
}
```

The output should be :

```
true true false
```

Comment: There are just two test case to verify this `isTrue` method, one is `==` to two numbers, another is `.equals`to two strings. Just implement `isTrue` with this lolgic.

Comment: Those test cases are just examples. It has to be implemented for any kind of condition.

Comment: Just use spring spel (unless you intentionally want to reinvent the wheel): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I hope you need that in your educational purpose and wouldn't use it in production environment (If you do so, I recommend you to learn parsing strings with Stack/Deque data structures). 
The roughest way how to achieve your aim is:

```
public class ConditionEvaluator {

    private String expression;

    public ConditionEvaluator(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    public boolean isTrue() throws Exception {
        if (expression.contains("==")) {
            return parseTwoEquals();
        } else if (expression.contains(".equals")) {
            return parseEquals();
        } else throw new Exception();

    }

    private boolean parseTwoEquals() throws Exception {
        String[] args = expression.split("==");
        if (args.length == 2) {
            return args[0].trim().equals(args[1].trim());
        } else throw new Exception();
    }

    private boolean parseEquals() throws Exception {
        String s = expression.replace("\"", "").replace("(", "").replace(")","");
        String[] split = s.split(".equals");
        if (split.length == 2) {
            return split[0].trim().equals(split[1].trim());
        } else throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The type of exception I believe you can create by yourself.